# sed - Remove Repeating Characters Character

Tags: sed

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove repeating characters with sed. We are given a file where certain words have repeating characters. The format is as follows:

> RREEPPEEAATTIINNGG
>
> some normal text
>
> HHEELLLLOO
>
> BBYYEE

The issue I am having is removing the repeating characters. My solution is to use backreferencing, `s/\(.\)\1/\1/g` but my teacher throws a curve-ball at me and tells me to try and do it without backreferences. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And it must be sed?

Comment: Back-references seem like the obvious way to do it.  Why does your teacher like curve balls?  Does he accept that back-references do the job?

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that in the sample data, only letters A, B, E, G, H, I, L, N, O, P, R, T, Y (all upper-case letters) are repeated?  Or only upper-case letters are repeated?  Clearly, you could write 26 upper-case repeat-eliminating substitutes, but that's … is stupid too strong? — no, it's about right … stupid when back-references do the job cleanly for upper-case or lower-case (or digits, or punctuation, or …) repeats.